# Mysql Remove Duplicates on Left Join 3 Tables using id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables

```
hobbies
+----+-------------+---------------+
| id | employeeid  | hobby_name    |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 |         123 | cooking       | 
|  2 |         123 | painting      | 
|  3 |         124 | dancing       | 
+----+-------------+---------------+

nonacad_recog
+----+-------------+---------------+
| id | employeeid  | recog_name    |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 |         123 | Award1        | 
|  2 |         123 | Award2        | 
|  3 |         124 | Award3        | 
+----+-------------+---------------+

org_membership

+----+-------------+---------------+
| id | employeeid  | recog_name    |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 |         123 | Boyscout      | 
|  2 |         124 | Girlscout     | 
+----+-------------+---------------+
```

This is the query I used:

```
SELECT h.hobby_name,r.recog_name,o.org_name
FROM hobbies as h 
JOIN nonacad_recog as r ON (h.employeeid=r.employeeid)
JOIN org_membership as o ON (r.employeeid=o.employeeid)
WHERE h.employeeid='123'
```

I am getting duplicate outputs:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+
| hobby_name | recog_name  | org_name    |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
|  cooking |         Award1 | Boyscout   | 
|  cooking |         Award2 | Boyscout   | 
|  painting|         Award1 | Boyscout   | 
|  painting|         Award2 | Boyscout   | 
+----+-------------+---------------------+
```

What I want as an output is like this: with no duplicates

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+
| hobby_name | recog_name  | org_name    |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
|  cooking |         Award1 | Boyscout   |
|  painting|         Award2 | NULL       | 
+----+-------------+---------------------+
```

also giving a null to the other columns/rows if there is nothing to return.
I might have missed out some things.

Is this possible to achieve using mysql queries?
Any solution to this?

If I get the correct table, it will be easy for me to 
mysqli_fetch assoc the results and display it on a table using PHP.

Comment: take a look at ORDER BY and DISTINCT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the desired output you want to relate rows in your tables by **non-existent column**, which is a row number.

You can technically do it like this

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN source = 1 THEN name END) hobby_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN source = 2 THEN name END) recog_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN source = 3 THEN name END) org_name
  FROM
(
  SELECT 1 source, id, hobby_name name, @n1 := @n1 + 1 rnum
    FROM hobbies CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n1 := 0) i
   WHERE employeeid = 123
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 source, id, recog_name, @n2 := @n2 + 1 rnum
    FROM nonacad_recog CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n2 := 0) i
   WHERE employeeid = 123
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 source, id, org_name, @n3 := @n3 + 1 rnum
    FROM org_membership CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n3 := 0) i
   WHERE employeeid = 123
   ORDER BY source, id
) q
 GROUP BY rnum
```

Output:

```
| HOBBY_NAME | RECOG_NAME | ORG_NAME |
|------------|------------|----------|
|    cooking |     Award1 | Boyscout |
|   painting |     Award2 |   (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/639aa/5)** demo

---

Here is an alternative solution. You pack all values as delimited strings with `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT hobby_name ORDER BY h.id) hobby_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recog_name ORDER BY r.id) recog_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT org_name ORDER BY o.id) org_name
  FROM
(
  SELECT 123 employeeid
) e LEFT JOIN hobbies h
    ON e.employeeid = h.employeeid 
    LEFT JOIN nonacad_recog r
    ON e.employeeid = r.employeeid 
    LEFT JOIN org_membership o
    ON e.employeeid = o.employeeid;
```

Output:

```
|       HOBBY_NAME |    RECOG_NAME | ORG_NAME |
|------------------|---------------|----------|
| cooking,painting | Award1,Award2 | Boyscout |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/639aa/11)** demo

and then in your client php code easily `explode()` column values while iterating over the resultset and build your presentation.

Comment: Man you are great! HATS OFF to you... can you please explain your code... logic is unclear to me..

Comment: HATS OFF!thank you Mr.peterm. if you could only explain it to us.

Comment: In the inner select you produce resultset from three tables enumerating rows, emitting a `source` column to keep track what tables values are coming from union all three result sets and order them by source (meaning table) and id to produce correct results. Then in the outer select we pivot it by performing conditional aggregation by row number.

Answer (score 1):

**I think "Limit" can work:**
SELECT h.hobby_name,r.recog_name,o.org_name
FROM hobbies as h, 
nonacad_recog as r,
org_membership as o
WHERE h.employeeid='123'
AND r.employeeid=o.employeeid
AND h.employeeid=r.employeeid
LIMIT 1